# djs get button on collect

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

```js
                    collector.on('collect', (ButtonInteraction) => {
                        let id = ButtonInteraction.customId

                    })
```

How can I get a button by ID. So I dont want to get the button I clicked. I want to get a specific button (in the buttonRow, too), so I can disable him
So is there a: `ButtonInteraction.getButtonByID('')` function or sth like that?
This is the row:

```js
    let row = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
        new MessageButton()
            .setEmoji('⏪')
            .setStyle('SECONDARY')
            .setCustomId('wL'),
        new MessageButton()
            .setEmoji('◀️')
            .setStyle('SECONDARY')
            .setCustomId('L'),
        new MessageButton()
            .setEmoji('▶️')
            .setStyle('SECONDARY')
            .setCustomId('R'),
        new MessageButton()
            .setEmoji('⏩')
            .setStyle('SECONDARY')
            .setCustomId('wR')
    )
```

I want to get for example the button with the custom id "wR" when clicking the button "R"

Answer (score 0):

Since you are setting a custom `Id` for the component via [`MessageComponentInteraction#customId`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageComponentInteraction?scrollTo=customId) property you may add an `if` condition to check for the `customId` you are looking for, like so:

```js
    collector.on('collect', (ButtonInteraction) => {
        let id = ButtonInteraction.customId
        if (id === "L") {
            collector.stop() console.log(`Clicked Button L`)
        }
        if (id === "R") {
            collector.stop() console.log(`Clicked Button R`)
        }
    });
```